# Java- SalesForce SOAP API integration- adding <wsse:Security> to SOAPHeader for

Tags: java, salesforce, integration, wsse

I am trying to connect to Salesforce from java client using SOAP api.  The integration requires me to add wsse:Secuirty headers to enter proxy credentials. Anyone has done this before?
I need to set wsse:security SoapHeader in my request, could not find any example of custom SOAP header for Java-SalesForce integration. Does anyone have experience with this?